# Obtaining databases for speech emotion recognition analysis

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-processing

For a research work on speech emotion recognition, I need the database of CASIA and EESDB for simulations. I could not find those; how can I get them? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CASIA can be obtained from Chinese LDC:

http://shachi.org/resources/27

Overall, it is easier to get experiments going with EMO-DB or to collect your own data from Youtube. Unsupervised learning from videos, like youtube videos tagged by uses with emotional tags might make more sense in a long term.